# Calculate a date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to substract exactly 6 month from a given date. How do you do this in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6) FROM dual
```

See [`ADD_MONTHS()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm).

Comment: +1 for the right answer, but mostly for including a link that references the most appropriate documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You write "I want to substract exactly 6 month from a given date". But what is "exactly 6 month" exactly? It's not trivial. For example, let's take 30th August, 2009. What date is exactly 6 months earlier? Or 28th February, 2009...

So you have to define what you mean and then decide which method you want to use:

- add_months(...,-6)
- -interval '6' month
- own code

An example:

```
SQL> select add_months(date '2009-08-30', -6)
  2       , add_months(date '2009-02-28', -6)
  3    from dual
  4  /

ADD_MONTHS(DATE'200 ADD_MONTHS(DATE'200
------------------- -------------------
28-02-2009 00:00:00 31-08-2008 00:00:00

1 row selected.

SQL> select date '2009-02-28' - interval '6' month
  2    from dual
  3  /

DATE'2009-02-28'-IN
-------------------
28-08-2008 00:00:00

1 row selected.

SQL> select date '2009-08-30' - interval '6' month
  2    from dual
  3  /
select date '2009-08-30' - interval '6' month
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
```

As you can see, there is a clear difference between add_months and the interval notation.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: good point, if the business says "we want it EXACTLY six months", you have to ask "what does that mean exactly?"

I've had cases where the business considers "one month" to be equal to 28 days.

Otherwise ADD_MONTHS is usually sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

add_months(..., -6)